# function returns wrong string after fetch json but console.log shows the correct one

Tags: react-native

here is my code:

```
export async function getAlbumArt(albumName) 
{
    fetch('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.search&album='+albumName+'&api_key=MYAPIKEY&format=json&limit=1')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
        const image = result.results.albummatches.album[0].image[2]['#text'];
        console.log(image);
        return image;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR: "+error);
    });
}
```

Function returns

```
{"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}
```

but console.log shows the correct string

```
https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/dfd01019404313399f77999285f78aa9.png
```

Comment: it's an 'async' function but where is the 'await' statement ?

Comment: @DiogoBrito I tried some solutions that I found online and I forgot remove "async".